# Getting fatal error Call to undefined function vc_set_template_dir()

Tags: php, wordpress

I just updated WP Bakery Page Builder plugin to latest version and getting this fatal error

`Call to undefined function vc_set_template_dir() in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php on line 272`

Here is the code on line 272 in `functions.php` file

```
$vcdir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/customvc/vc_templates/';
    vc_set_template_dir( $vcdir );
```

`vc_set_template_directory` function is creating problems.

Comment: `vc_set_template_directory` and `vc_set_template_dir` is not the same... check the name of your function

Comment: sorry, its vc_set_template_dir . as I copied the code in my question.

Comment: According to [this page](https://codecanyon.net/item/visual-composer-page-builder-for-wordpress/242431/comments?from_buyers_and_authors_only=0&order_by=newest&page=1&term=url+undefined&utf8=%E2%9C%93) you can fix this by replacing the name of the function `vc_set_template_dir` with `vc_set_shortcodes_template_dir`

Answer (score 2):

Like Jamie_D said, you need to replace the vc_set_template_directory function with vc_set_shortcodes_templates_dir. there is a small typo in his answer. Here is the documentation https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/inner-api/vc_set_shortcodes_templates_dir/

e.g.

```
$vcdir = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/customvc/vc_templates/';
vc_set_shortcodes_templates_dir( $vcdir );
```